# Algorithm to discover long n-gram using limited memory?

Tags: algorithm

What memory efficient algorithms exist for counting large n-grams. I have a large number of binary inputs (~1k) and want to discover (using an on-line algorithm) which subsets occur together more frequently than average. Am thinking that the problem is isomorphic with searching for long n-grams (with each input equivalent to a character or word), unfortunately creating a couple of terabytes worth of tables to do a simple tally is out of the question (this is going into javascript so one gigabyte would be pushing it). Am hoping somebody can point me towards some clever algorithms or ideas that I could tweak.

I don't need to keep exact numbers, just observe when say there is a subset of ten or so inputs that occur together frequently.

Comment: Maybe start with counting bigrams, then look at what bigrams appear most often and then count just longer n-grams containing those bigrams? (Optionally add some intermediate steps with trigrams, fourgrams, etc. if space is much more valuable than time.)

Comment: @tobias_k, won't work. maybe there are 5 (10's) and 8 (01's). Then, all 5 10's end up as 101's and only 4 01's end up as 010's, while other 4 as 011's. Now the correct answer will be 101, possibility of finding which is already discarded by your algo.

Comment: Thanks, had been thinking along those terms but it occurred to me that say a 10-gram that occurred maybe three times  in a million would be very interesting, while if the constituent bi-grams themselves only ever occurred as part of that 10-gram (i.e. only three times in a million) then there would never have been any reason to count those bi-grams leading to the discovery.

Comment: @vish4071 I see your point: It could be that the most frequent bigram is not part of the most-frequent 10-gram at all. Well, still the approach could be used to find, say, all 10-grams that appear at least k times, as all their constituting bi-grams have to have appeared at least k times. Of course, you still have to actually count them (the bigrams could have appeared k times as part of other words), but you can save memory by not counting any 10-grams whose bigrams appear less than k times.

Comment: Is there any limit to `n` - size of your `n-gram`??

Comment: `and want to discover (using an on-line algorithm) which subsets occur together more frequently than average`. You should know that n-grams just cover sequences and not all possible sets.

Comment: Ideally n would be open ended, but 10 seems like an adequate number for theorizing.

Comment: @svs what can be represented by a sequence is a superset of what can be represented by a set? [1,2,3,4] and [4,3,2,1] are both equivalent to the set {1,2,3,4}... well they are for my purposes anyway - I'm sure a mathematician would rebuke me though (I will be normalizing the order of the input set, so should have no problem fitting as ngram sequence)

Comment: can you state properly what are you trying to do because I have the feeling n-grams won't help you. you say you want subsets, n-grams cover subsets - yes but not all. Imagine you had the sequence [1,2,3,4]. You'd count [2,3] but you'd never count [1,4] since it's not a n-gram

Comment: Say I have 1024 bits as input, that 1024 bit value changing with the clock. If I consider each bit as the presence of a letter in the (rather large) alphabet, and consider the collection of letters together as a word... While you are correct it is not EXACTLY an n-gram the problem is still close enough that I am confident I can massage an n-gram algorithm to fit my purposes. I chose to specify n-grams as it is a more general problem and therefore more likely to have existing solutions... (My actual task is automatically discovering candidate hidden layer nodes for training a neural net)

Comment: From your comment, I don't think n-grams are the right approach at all. As I understand you, the first bit might stand for "A", the second for "B", and so on, up to the 1024th bit. Now consider the trigram "111". Depending on where in the string it is located, it could correspond to "ABC", or "HIJ", or "XYZ". Also, using n-grams you could not find words with letters that are not close together in the alphabet. But maybe I totally misunderstood that comment; in this case, please clarify.

Comment: OK, forget I mentioned anything about bits and bit positions - let's just say I have a 1024 character alphabet and need to find long sequences  of these characters that occur more than once (each 'sequence' corresponding to all the active inputs during one frame)

Comment: - the only difference I see from my perspective between these 'sequences' and a more traditional n-gram are 1) no repeating characters. 2) the order of the characters is irelevent since the source is a set... both factors I would expect to make the task slightly easier compared to dealing with normal n-grams

Comment: Could one rephrase the question as: "Given a number of sets (with sizes <=1000), determine all subsets (with sizes ~10) that appear in a larger fraction of those sets?"

Comment: One could, it just seems rephrasing that way looses generality and gets one further away from finding someone with knowledge of a solution.

Comment: Well, the problem with "n-grams" is that n-grams _have_ order, while you do not care about order. Also, n-grams are indifferent to the location in the string where they appear, while this seems to matter to you. And finally, using 10-grams you can only find groups of bits at most 9 positions apart. All in all, I really don't think n-grams will help you, and sticking to this term will not help you either.

Comment: Thank you for your input - we seem to have differing opinions on whether the n-gram model can be made to fit my problem... all the same my question still stands as to what algorithms exist for discovering long reoccurring n-grams (apart from creating exhaustive tables of counts).